# How to execute a php code from a button in a pop-up modal?

Tags: javascript, php

I am trying to accept application forms display in a 2nd Modal which pops up after the first 1 with an accept button for each account displayed. What happens is when the first modal shows, the list of the applicators would show in a modal, then when you press the Information button(which is working) another modal would pop-up with the applicator's info in it. Then there's an accept button in the 2nd modal in which doesn't work.

I have tried calling an ajax function but it does not seem to work. The function can't recognize a button pressed from a modal it seems.

I have this php as my modal

```
 <?php  
@session_start();
 if(isset($_POST["post_id"]))  
 {  
      $output = '';  
      $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "adappdb");  
////////////////////////////////////////////////
      /*STATUS CHANGE START*/
      $query = "SELECT * FROM adoption_application WHERE application_id = '".$_POST["post_id"]."'";  
      $result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);  
      $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

      if ($row['appli_status']==0){
        $newAStatus = 1;
      }else if ($row['appli_status']==1){
        $newAStatus = 2;
      }else if ($row['appli_status']==2){
        $newAStatus = 3;
      }else if ($row['appli_status']==3){
        $newAStatus = 4;
      }else if ($row['appli_status']==4){
        $newAStatus = 5;
      }

      $query = "UPDATE adoption_application SET appli_status='$newAStatus' WHERE application_id = '".$_POST["post_id"]."'";
      mysqli_query($connect, $query);

      if ($row['appli_status']==0){
        $newAS = "On Process";
      }else if ($row['appli_status']==1){
        $newAS = "Waiting for Initial Interview";
      }else if ($row['appli_status']==2){
        $newAS = "Occular";
      }else if ($row['appli_status']==3){
        $newAS = "Waiting for Approval";
      }else if ($row['appli_status']==4){
        $newAS = "Adopted";
      }

      /*STATUS CHANGE END*/
       $query = "SELECT * FROM adoption_application WHERE application_id = '".$_POST["post_id"]."'";  
      $result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);
////////////////////////////////////////////////
      $output .= '  
      <div class="table-responsive">  
           <table class="table table-bordered"> 
           '; 
      while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))  
      {  
           $output .= '  
                <tr>  
                     <td width="30%"><label>First Name</label></td>  
                     <td width="50%">'.$row["appli_fname"].'</td> 
                </tr>
                <tr>
                     <td width="30%"><label>Last Name</label></td>
                     <td width="50%">'.$row["appli_lname"].'</td>  
                </tr>  
                <tr>
                     <td width="30%"><label>Status</label></td>
                     <td width="50%">'.$newAS.'</td>  
                </tr>  

           ';  
      }  

      $output .= '  
           </table>  
           <button type="button" name="proceeding_process" data-toggle="modal" href="#application_dataModal3"  class="btn btn-primary bt-xs accept" id="'.$row["application_id"].'">Next Stage</button>
      </div>  
      ';  
      echo $output;  
 }  
 ?>
```

and What I've tried adding from the php of the website is the javascript

```
$(document).on('click', '.accept', function(){  
           var post_id = $(this).attr("id");  
           if(post_id != '')  
           {  
                $.ajax({  
                     url:"organization_createpost_proceedingprocess.php",  
                     method:"POST",  
                     data:{post_id:post_id},  
                     success:function(data){  
                          $('#proceeding_process').html(data);  
                          $('#application_dataModal3').modal('show');  
                     }  
                });  
           }            
      });
```

Even if it won't work in the ajax. What my main goal is to execute this code when Accept or Next Stage button is pressed. It is for updating the applicator's status in the database.

```````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````
      $query = "SELECT * FROM adoption_application WHERE application_id = '".$_POST["post_id"]."'";  
      $result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);  
      $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

      if ($row['appli_status']==0){
        $newAStatus = 1;
      }else if ($row['appli_status']==1){
        $newAStatus = 2;
      }else if ($row['appli_status']==2){
        $newAStatus = 3;
      }else if ($row['appli_status']==3){
        $newAStatus = 4;
      }else if ($row['appli_status']==4){
        $newAStatus = 5;
      }

      $query = "UPDATE adoption_application SET appli_status='$newAStatus' WHERE application_id = '".$_POST["post_id"]."'";
      mysqli_query($connect, $query);

      if ($row['appli_status']==0){
        $newAS = "On Process";
      }else if ($row['appli_status']==1){
        $newAS = "Waiting for Initial Interview";
      }else if ($row['appli_status']==2){
        $newAS = "Occular";
      }else if ($row['appli_status']==3){
        $newAS = "Waiting for Approval";
      }else if ($row['appli_status']==4){
        $newAS = "Adopted";
      }

      /*STATUS CHANGE END*/

``````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````

/*Here is my whole javascript code:*/

``````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
        // all of your JavaScript/jQuery code
        // for example, the function in question:
        /*$(document).on('click', '.accept', function(){
            ...
        });*/
function confirmation()
{
  var x = confirm("Are you sure you want to Logout?")
  if(x==true)
  {
    return true;
  }
  else
  {
    return false;
  }
}

    });

</script>

<script>  
   $(document).ready(function() {
    fetch_data();

        // all of your JavaScript/jQuery code
        // for example, the function in question:
        /*$(document).on('click', '.accept', function(){
            ...
        });*/
///////////////////////////////////////

        function fetch_data()
 {
  var oid = "<?php echo $copy; ?>";
  var action = "fetch";
  $.ajax({
   url:"organization_post_action.php",
   method:"POST",
   data:{oid:oid,
        action:action},
   success:function(data)
   {
    $('#image_data').html(data);
    $('#pet_name').val(data.pet_name);
    $('#pet_type').val(data.pet_type);
    $('#pet_breed').val(data.pet_breed);
    $('#pet_color').val(data.pet_color);
    $('#pet_bdate').val(data.pet_bdate);
    $('#post_notes').val(data.post_notes);

   }
  })
 }

/////////////////////////////////////////

$('#add').click(function(){
  var elem = document.getElementById('valUD');
   elem.style.display='none';
      $('#imageModal').modal('show');
      $('#image_form')[0].reset();
      $('.modal-title').text("Add post");
      $('#image_id').val('');


      $('#action').val('insert');
      $('#insert').val("Insert");
 });

///////////////////////////////////////

$('#image_form').submit(function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  var image_name = $('#image').val();

  if(pet_name == ''){
     alert("Please input pet name");
   return false;
  }
  else if(pet_type == ''){
     alert("Please input pet type");
   return false;
  }
  else if(pet_breed == ''){
     alert("Please input pet breed");
   return false;
  }
  else if(pet_color == ''){
     alert("Please input pet color");
   return false;
  }
  else if(pet_bdate == ''){
     alert("Please input pet birthdate");
   return false;
  }
  else if(post_notes == ''){
     alert("Please input post notes");
   return false;
  }
  else
  {
    if(image_name != '')
  {

   var extension = $('#image').val().split('.').pop().toLowerCase();
   if(jQuery.inArray(extension, ['gif','png','jpg','jpeg']) == -1)
   {
    alert("Invalid Image File");
    $('#image').val('');
    return false;
   }
   else
   {
    $.ajax({
     url:"organization_post_action.php",
     method:"POST",
     data:new FormData(this),
     contentType:false,
     processData:false,
     success:function(data)
     {
      alert(data);
      fetch_data();
      $('#image_form')[0].reset();
      $('#imageModal').modal('hide');
     }
    });
   }
   }else{
     $.ajax({
        url:"organization_post_action.php",
        method:"POST",
        data:new FormData(this),
        contentType:false,
        processData:false,

        success:function(data){
            alert(data);
            fetch_data();
            $('#image_form')[0].reset();
            $('#imageModal').modal('hide');
        }
    });
   }
  }
 });

 //////////////////////

 $(document).on('click', '.view_data', function(){  
           var post_id = $(this).attr("id");  
           if(post_id != '')  
           {  
                $.ajax({  
                     url:"organization_createpost_fetch.php",  
                     method:"POST",  
                     data:{post_id:post_id}, 
                     dataType:"json",   
                     success:function(data){
                          $('#pet_name1').val(data.pet_name);
                          $('#pet_type1').val(data.pet_type);  
                          $('#pet_breed1').val(data.pet_breed);  
                          $('#pet_color1').val(data.pet_color);  
                          $('#pet_bdate1').val(data.pet_bdate);
                          $('#post_notes1').val(data.post_notes);
                          $('#posted_by').val(data.posted_by);
                          $('#date_created').val(data.date_created);

                          $('#image_id').val($(this).attr("id"));
                          $('#action').val("update");
                          $('.modal-title').text("Pet Information");
                          $('#pet_detail').html(data);  
                          $('#dataModal').modal('show');  
                     }  
                });  
           }            
  }); 

 ////////////////////

 $(document).on('click', '.update', function(){
   var elem = document.getElementById('valUD');
   elem.style.display='block';

    var post_id = $(this).attr("id"); 
    $.ajax({  
                url:"organization_createpost_fetch.php",  
                method:"POST",  
                data:{post_id:post_id},  
                dataType:"json",  
                success:function(data){  
                     $('#pet_name').val(data.pet_name);  
                     $('#pet_type').val(data.pet_type);  
                     $('#pet_breed').val(data.pet_breed);  
                     $('#pet_color').val(data.pet_color);
                     $('#post_notes').val(data.post_notes);
                    $('#image_id').val(data.post_id);

                      $('#action').val("update");
                      $('.modal-title').text("Update Pet Information"); 
                     $('#insert').val("Update");  
                    $('#imageModal').modal('show');
                }  
           });



 });

 ////////////////

 $(document).on('click', '.adoption', function(){  
           var post_id = $(this).attr("id");  
           if(post_id != '')  
           {  
                $.ajax({  
                     url:"organization_createpost_adoption.php",  
                     method:"POST",  
                     data:{post_id:post_id},  
                     success:function(data){  
                          $('#action').val("update");
                          $('#list_application').html(data);  
                          $('#application_dataModal').modal('show');  
                     }  
                });  
           }            
  });

 //////////////////

$(document).on('click', '.information', function(){ 
console.log('clicked information'); 
           var post_id = $(this).attr("id");  
           if(post_id != '')  
           {  
                $.ajax({  
                     url:"organization_createpost_information.php",  
                     method:"POST",  
                     data:{post_id:post_id},  
                     success:function(data){  
                          $('#information_application').html(data);  
                          $('#application_dataModal2').modal('show');  
                     }  
                });  
           }            
});

///////////////////

$(document).on('click', '.accept', function(){  
          console.log('clicked accept');
           var post_id = $(this).attr("id");  
           if(post_id != '')  
           {  
                $.ajax({  
                     url:"organization_createpost_proceedingprocess.php",  
                     method:"POST",  
                     data:{post_id:post_id},  
                     success:function(data){  
                          $('#proceeding_process').html(data);  
                          $('#application_dataModal3').modal('show');  
                     }  
                });  
           }            
});

/////////////////////

$(document).on('click', '.proceeding_process', function(){  
           var post_id = $(this).attr("id");  
           if(post_id != '')  
           {  
                $.ajax({  
                     url:"organization_createpost_proceedingprocess.php",  
                     method:"POST",  
                     data:{post_id:post_id},  
                     success:function(data){  
                          $('#proceeding_process').html(data);  
                          $('#application_dataModal3').modal('show');  
                     }  
                });  
           }            
});

///////////

});

</script>

```````````````````````````````````````````
```````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion or debugging sessions; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192281/discussion-on-question-by-boggart-how-to-execute-a-php-code-from-a-button-in-a-p).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to wrap all of your jQuery (and even VanillaJS) functions in *one* ready function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        // all of your JavaScript/jQuery code
        // for example, the function in question:
        $(document).on('click', '.accept', function(){
            ...
        });
    });
</script>
```

The one function we're discussing here, the `.accept` function is *not* wrapped with a ready function at all, and is therefore failing.

If you'd like, there is a shorthand version:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        // all of your JavaScript/jQuery code here
    });
</script>
```

Comment: After retyping my codes, I just noticed that the reason the accept button wont work is that my co-developer have interchanged the button name for the 'Next Stage' and the 'Accept' buttons. I'm really sorry for having this drag out. I wasn't knowledgeable in the codes structure as I am the one responsible for the Mobile App. You're really a great help. Thank you a lot. You have been really helpful for me.